# Threadlocking on the ViewModel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I have the a WPF app that calls a Webservice async with two objects of the same class. The resulting response collection from both of the call's eventhandlers should be put into the same dictionary that is a databound to the UI.
My problem is threadlocks when webservices return the collection and tries to insert into the same dictionary.

```
public class myClass : Window
{
    public MyService serv1 {get;set;}
    public MyService serv2 {get;set;}

    public ObservableDictionary<string, MySertvice> dict = new ObservableDictionary<string, MySertvice>();

    public ObservableDictionary<string, MySertvice> Dict_VM {get;set;}


    public myClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent()
        this.DataContext = Dict;

        serv1 = new MyService("serviceA");
        serv1.CallBack += CallBack;

        serv2 = new MyService("serviceB");
        serv2.CallBack += CallBack;
    }

    public Window_Loaded(object sender, WindowloadedEventArgs e)
    {
        serv1.DoServiceCallAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("- first call");
        serv2.DoServiceCallAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("- second call");
    }

    public void CallBack(object sender, CallBackEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("- callback");
        foreach(var name in e.ResultCollection)
        {
            dict.Add(name, sender as MyService);
        }
    }
}
```

output is:

- first call
- second call
- callback
- callback

My question is, What would be the best way to make it thread safe?

This is just a sample, so the ogic does not matter. I would like to every element of the ResultCollection. My first thoughts have been to transfer the results into a Queue or ConcurrentQueue and have a a Background worker process it from the Queue into the Dictionary. I would really like the best approach

Comment: Why not use [`ConcurrentObservableDictionary`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208361/Concurrent-Observable-Collection-Dictionary-and-So)

Comment: does adding items to a collection have to be thread safe..?
could you describe a problematic scenario ? 
What i mean is , why do you have an issue with adding objects (A,B,C) concurrently with objects (D,E,F) .? 

Do you require that the first call to return must complete adding items before the second call can begin adding it's items ?

Comment: Yes it has to. The multiple async callback have to be able to add to the object at the same time. This is a sample with two services, where in reality (my real world scenario) I have a collection of services. It has to collect real time monitoring data. the time of the processing of individual services is crucial

Comment: Why not marshall the updates onto the UI thread using the Dispatcher?  The Dispatcher is thread safe and manages multiple calls perfectly well.  You would only be simulating it by spawning a thread to service a ConcurrentQueue into which you feed results.

Comment: can you provide me with an example or a link?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. If you are not confident of Concurrency Collection then:

```
private Object thisLock = new Object();

public void CallBack(object sender, CallBackEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("- callback");
    lock(thisLock )
    {            
        foreach(var name in e.ResultCollection)
        {
            dict.Add(name, sender as MyService);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: would this lock the dict for the for the first one, and the other would be on hold until the first one is complete? 
Would The pattern of processing be like AAAAABBBBB or would it be more like ABAABBBABA?

Comment: This will be the pattern of processing be like AAAAABBBBB. Lock is always  thread safe, but it cost the performance.

Comment: I was suspecting this. How can I achieve the ABAABBBABA pattern. I guess the concurrent collection?

Comment: I can't because you change the list. Some concurrency collections is list-blocked, and/or item-blocked.

Comment: would adding one by one to a concurrentQueue (from both) do the trick. I want to achieve the effect of a funnel. Have multiples pour in data and have it processed as it is possible. This is why I was thinking of a  Backgroudworker doing the processing.

Comment: or, what if I move the lock into the loop?

Comment: You can use concurrency queue if still lock dictionary. If no lock, race condition can occur. Because many threads concurrently add items to dictionary.